# Writing exif data to the exif header using PyExifTool

Tags: python-3.x, exif, exiftool

Looking over a post from 2015 [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27815719/editing-updating-the-data-of-photo-metadata-using-pyexiftool) on how to use PyExifTool to write to the Exif header. I gave it a try:

```
import exiftool
fileno=r'DSC00001.JPG
with exiftool.ExifTool() as et:
    et.execute("EXIF:GPSLongitude=100",fileno)
    et.execute("EXIF:GPSLatitude=100",fileno)
```

In response, I got the following error:

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected a bytes-like object, str found
```

Then as specified in the [documentation](http://smarnach.github.io/pyexiftool/#), execute takes byte commands, so I bites, so I tried that too:

```
with exiftool.ExifTool() as et:
   et.execute(bytes("EXIF:GPSLongitude=100", 'utf-8'),fileno)
   et.execute(bytes("EXIF:GPSLatitude=50",'utf-8'),fileno)
```

But still got the same error :

```
TypeError: sequence item 1: expected a bytes-like object, str found
```

I am not sure what am I doing wrong, and if Exiftool can write to file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#Gracias!

    exif = r'...\exiftool.exe'
    file=br"...\FRM_20220111_134802.JPG"
    
    with exiftool.ExifTool(exif) as et:
        et.execute(b"-DateTimeOriginal=2022:10:10 10:10:10", file)
        tag = et.get_tag("EXIF:DateTimeOriginal", file)
        ...

#RCM_Chile
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `execute` method is low-level and requires bytes as inputs for **both** the parameters you pass **and** the file name. Try this:

```
import exiftool
pic = b"DSC00001.JPG"
with exiftool.ExifTool() as et:
    et.execute(b"-GPSLatitude=11.1", pic)
    tag = et.get_tag("EXIF:GPSLatitude", pic)
    print(tag)
```

Comment: I think your suggestion is in the right direction. Problem is there are some cases when an error is not raised, and I think this is one of them. When I run the code with your suggestions, print(tag) returns NONE.  Even if you try et.get_metadata(pic), there is no GPS information.

Comment: Check my latest edit. To actually write the tag you need to use the form: "-TAG=VALUE" instead of "EXIF:TAG" format. If you use the code above in its current form it should work and "print(tag)" should now return a value.