# How to read and write xp_style exif image meta-tags using python?

Tags: python, image, metadata, exif

I'm trying to automate writing image meta-tags using [exif](https://pypi.org/project/exif/) python package. but I found out that my images contain xp_style metatags. I want to replace them with my arbitrary text.
when I'm trying to do that. I get this error.

```
**This package does not yet support setting Windows XP style tags**
```

**NotImplementedError: this package does not yet support setting Windows XP style tags**

This is my code snippet:

```
from exif import Image

folder_path = 'sample_images'
img_filename = '1.jpg'
img_path = folder_path+'/'+img_filename

with open(img_path, 'rb') as img_file:
    img = Image(img_file)

if img.has_exif:
    img.artist = "MY_ARTIST"
    img.xp_author = "MY_AUTHOR"
    img.xp_keywords = "MY_KEYWORDS"

    print(f'ARTIST: {img.get("artist")}')
    print(f'AUTHOR: {img.get("xp_author")}')
    print(f'KEYWORDS: {img.get("xp_keywords")}')
```

Can anyone suggest to me a package that is capable of writing xp_style metadata or an alternate way to do this?

Comment: You might look at [PyExifTool](https://smarnach.github.io/pyexiftool/), which is a python wrapper for [ExifTool](https://exiftool.org/).  But you might also want to look at trying to move away from the XP* tags, as they are pretty much Windows only and have almost no support outside of that.  The IPTC Core/Ext standard is newer and more future proof.

Comment: @StarGeekStart Thanks for the suggestion. You saved me a lot of time. PyExifTool solved a half of my problem. I'm using it only to read metadata because I couldn't find a way to write using PyExifTool. I'm using ExifTool with subprocess to write new metadata.

Comment: For writing, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50940588/3525475).  It does require some knowledge of exiftool parameters but the basics you would put in the `execute` statement are `-TAG=VALUE`.  So in the case of the XP* tags, you would use `-XPAuthor=Name` `-XPKeywords=Keyword 1;Keyword 2`   Note that `XPKeywords` is a semicolon separated string.  This is different than other keyword tags such as `IPTC:Keywords` and `XMP:Subject`, which are lists.