# Is there a method to write metadata to an image in PyExifTool?

Tags: python, image-processing, metadata, gis, exiftool

I used **ExifTool**'s '-tagsFromFile' to copy Exif metadata from a source image to a destination image from the command line. Wanted to do the same in a python script, which is when I got to know of **PyExifTool**. However, I didn't find any command to copy or write to a destination image. Am I missing something? Is there a way I can fix this?

I found **user5008949**'s answer to a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27815719/editing-updating-the-data-of-photo-metadata-using-pyexiftool) which suggested doing this:

```
import exiftool
filename = '/home/radha/src.JPG'
with exiftool.ExifTool() as et:
    et.execute("-tagsFromFile",  filename , "dst.JPG")
```

However, it gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "metadata.py", line 9, in <module>
    et.execute("-tagsFromFile",  filename , "dst.JPG")
  File "/home/radha/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/exiftool.py", line 221, in execute
    self._process.stdin.write(b"\n".join(params + (b"-execute\n",)))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected a bytes-like object, str found
```

Comment: I found piexif which is an easier alternative to PyExifTool with clearer documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`execute()` method requires bytes as inputs and you are passing strings. That is why it fails.

In your case, the code should look like this:

```
import exiftool
filename = b"/home/radha/src.JPG"
with exiftool.ExifTool() as et:
    et.execute(b"-tagsFromFile",  filename , b"dst.JPG")
```

Please find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50940588) answer as a refernece.

Comment: I had moved on from this project, but it was a simple thing to test out. It works, thanks!